# How to evaluate a group of records in MS Access and get a single result

Tags: ms-access

I'm using MS Access and I'm trying evaluate a subset of records to generate a single value for that group in a Report.  If all records for that group are TRUE then the group is TRUE. I all are FALSE then the Group evaluates to FALSE.  If mixed then the group should evaluate to BOTH

I have the following type of data that is grouped by name and then grouped by department

```
Name1
    dept1
         Job1       True 
         Job2       True

Name2
    dept1
         Job1       False
         Job2       False

Name3
    dept1
         Job1       False
         Job2       True
```

The Name1 group would be TRUE, the Name2 group would be False and the Name3 group would be BOTH.  Is there a non-VBA way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Update:
There is only a single table (imported from excel) with field names (ID, Name, Dept, Task, JobStatus).

Data is as follows:

```
╔════╦══════╦══════╦════════════════════════╦═══════════╗
║ ID ║ Name ║ Dept ║          Task          ║TaskStatus ║
╠════╬══════╬══════╬════════════════════════╬═══════════║
║  1 ║ Jen  ║   01 ║ CC THEA PROD 2A        ║ TRUE      ║           
║  2 ║ Jen  ║   01 ║ CC THEA PROD 3B        ║ TRUE      ║           
║  3 ║ Jen  ║   02 ║ CC THEA PROD 1A        ║ FALSE     ║           
║  4 ║ Ted  ║   01 ║ TCHR EDUC TRNG I       ║ TRUE      ║           
║  5 ║ Ted  ║   01 ║ TCHR EDUC TRNG II      ║ FALSE     ║           
║  6 ║ Ted  ║   03 ║ CS PRINT AP            ║ FALSE     ║           
║  7 ║ Ted  ║   03 ║ CONF-HS                ║ FALSE     ║
║  8 ║ Ben  ║   02 ║ CC INFO MGMT           ║ TRUE      ║        
║  9 ║ Ben  ║   02 ║ ECON MOD PT            ║ TRUE      ║        
║ 10 ║ Ben  ║   05 ║ MMAN ISO               ║ TRUE      ║        
╚════╩══════╩══════╩════════════════════════╩═══════════╝
```

Comment: Are these records in tables that you can directly query with SQL, or is this data represented by objects in VBA?

Comment: Yes, if it is on report then you can use expression on a textbox at group footer.

Comment: @Dai Yes the data is in tables in MS Access.  I am not using VBA at all and and need a no-=VBA solution

Comment: @Harun24HR I attempted a couple of expressions but was not able to figure it out. Can you expand on your response?

Comment: Then please post your table schemas (`CREATE TABLE...`) statements and examples of the data they contain.

Comment: @Dai  Post has been updated.  Not sure how to get the schema out of Access.

Comment: @PvSyemya There's always the "Database documentation" feature - which is close enough.

Comment: Try this: `SELECT [Id], [Name], IIF( SUM( TaskStatus ) = 0, 'FALSE', IIF( SUM( TaskStatus ) = COUNT( TaskStatus ), 'TRUE', 'BOTH' ) AS GroupStatus FROM [table] GROUP BY [Id], [Name]`

Comment: @PvSyemya Can you please check my answer?

Comment: @Dai I tried your SQL as A Query and it returned "Syntax error (missing operator)..." and the "AS" is highlighted in SQL screen.

Comment: @Harun24HR You got me on the right path which I now see is the same as what you proposed. I was able to incorporate an expression in the Grouping.  I ended up using  a nested IIF statement:    =IIf((Sum(IIf([Task Status]=-1,1,0))>0) And (Sum(IIf([Task Status]=0,1,0))>0),"Both",IIf((Sum(IIf([Task Status]=-1,1,0))=0) And (Sum(IIf([Task Status]=0,1,0))>0),"False","True"))

Comment: So did it finally solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was meaning in comment. I have designed a report like below with `Dept` Footer section.

[image]

Then add a `TextBox` in `Dept` footer section and write below expression.

```
=IIf(Count(*)=Sum(IIf([TaskStatus]=True,1,0)),"TRUE",IIf(Count(*)=Sum(IIf([TaskStatus]=False,1,0)),"FALSE","BOTH"))
```

***This is the result I got.***
[image]

> ***Edit#***

If you want it as result of SQL query output then use below query. Please note ***`Name`*** is reserve word so I use `tName` instead of `Name`. Change table name and field name for your case.

```
SELECT t.tName, t.Dept, 

IIF(Count(t.TaskStatus)=DCount("TaskStatus","Table1","tName='" & t.tName & "' AND Dept='" & t.Dept & "' AND TaskStatus='TRUE'"),"TRUE",
IIF(Count(t.TaskStatus)=DCount("TaskStatus","Table1","tName='" & t.tName & "' AND Dept='" & t.Dept & "' AND TaskStatus='FALSE'"),"FALSE","BOTH"))

AS Result FROM Table1 AS t
GROUP BY t.tName, t.Dept;
```

[image]

Comment: Note: I have used `TaskStatus` and `Yes/No` datatype in table design. If your datatype is `ShortText` then you have to use `=IIf(Count(*)=Sum(IIf([TaskStatus]="TRUE",1,0)),"TRUE",IIf(Count(*)=Sum(IIf([TaskStatus]="FALSE",1,0)),"FALSE","BOTH"))`

Comment: I'm getting an error with the SQL and can't see my mistake. I've taken out the 2nd IIF statement to see if I could narrow the problem down, but it still shows "#Error" in the Result column.<br/>SELECT t.NameShort, t.Dept, 

IIf(Count(t.TaskStatus)=DCount("TaskStatus","SOF_Test","NameShort='" & t.NameShort & "' AND Dept='" & t.Dept & "' AND TaskStatus='TRUE'"),"TRUE","FALSE")

AS Result
FROM SOF_Test AS t
GROUP BY t.NameShort, t.Dept;

Comment: If you see my SQL query, you need to place single quote and double quote correctly. You are missing single quote in `DCount()` function.

Comment: Thanks I got this working. I was missing a comma too.